# Requests get stuck in PG::Connection#async_exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, passenger

I'm trying to make a `rails` application work under `passenger` with no luck so far. It uses `sequel` to connect to `postgresql`. Requests randomly take too much time to complete. I was able to find where the app is spending its time:

```
 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 99.92     65.713    65.713     0.000     0.000        5   PG::Connection#async_exec
  0.00      0.002     0.002     0.000     0.000      264   Set#delete
...
```

Supposedly, it doesn't happen with `webrick`, and I'm going to try and run it under `unicorn`.

Here are some [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029888/how-to-debug-requests-taking-too-much-time-when-using-passenger/40044386#40044386) [links](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/iQ2a_jzaK54).

I'm using `passenger-5.0.30`, `ruby-2.3.0`, `postgresql-9.4`, `pg-0.19.0`, `rails-5.0.0.1`. The same goes for `unicorn-5.1.0`. The app is running in `lxc` container. Host and guest OSs are `ubuntu/xenial`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved after we started reestablishing connections to database. We were using `sequel` on the project, and Passenger handles the issue itself only when ActiveRecord is used.

To expand on it, by default Passenger uses smart spawning for ruby apps. It first spawns preloader process, which loads framework and all the libraries. After that preloader process spawns worker processes when the need arises, which handle the requests. When spawning worker processes, all file descriptors are inherited from preloader process. So if you don't reestablish connection to database, all worker process share one, established by preloader. Which leads to all sorts of weird behavior. Like requests taking too long.

Before that, we also moved handling WebSocket connections to a separate process. Not sure if it contributed to the issue however.

More on that here:

[Disconnect If Using Forking Webserver with Code Preloading](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/code_order_rdoc.html#label-Disconnect+If+Using+Forking+Webserver+with+Code+Preloading)
[Unintentional file descriptor sharing](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/spawn_methods/#unintentional-file-descriptor-sharing)
[Running the Action Cable server on the same host and port, under a sub-URI](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/action_cable_integration/#running-the-action-cable-server-on-the-same-host-and-port-under-a-sub-uri)